# Passive voice use with BE + PAST PARTICIPLE with BE remaining in its infinitive form

Tags: passive-voice

> The judge ordered that smoking BE PROHIBITED in restaurants.

Could someone explain the use of the passive form in this sentence? Does it have anything to do with an imperative command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is (a rare) [use of a subjunctive.](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/subjunctive.htm)

The verb "order" is one that allows for a subjunctive "that" clause.  Other verbs that allow the subjunctive include "suggest", "recommend" or "request".

Then the structure is "order that {it} {subjunctive verb}". Here {it} is smoking, and the subjunctive verb has exactly the same form as the base infinitive. Here's another example with different verbs.

> John suggested that Mary play tennis.

The use of the subjunctive is formal.

Comment: British English would tend to avoid subjunctive and say "The judge ordered that smoking should be prohibited"

Comment: And this subjunctive (the "present subjunctive") is **in every single verb of the language** identical with the base form/infinitive, so I simply don't understand why people hang on to giving it a special name. I prefer to say that in some varieties of English (especially formal ones, and especially in American English) the verbs that you list are followed by the base form/infinitive without "to".

Comment: @JamesK In "***ordered** that smoking **should** be prohibited*", is that an order or a recommendation?

Comment: When a judge says it...Actually you could easily avoid subjunctive completely:  The judge prohibited smoking in restaurants.